# Unable to Set Up Remote Access on Windows Home Server

Tags: windows-home-server, remote-access, hp-mediasmart

When trying to turn on Remote Access on my Windows Home Server (HP MediaSmart Ex485, MediaSmart Server 3.0, Power Pack 3), I am not able to continue through the wizard as this first check fails:

> "Verifying that your remote Web site is available locally"

Everything else on the server works fine, including being able to:

- Ping server
- RDP to server
- Access all shares as expected
- Browse to both http://servername and http://servername:55000

I have noticed though that I am **unable** to browse to http://servername:56000 as I should be able to do.

I've performed a server recovery to reset the installation to factory defaults, with no such luck.

Comment: Do you use a router, and if so, what kind is it?  Also, are you using OpenDNS as a DNS provider?

Comment: I am using a router (ASUS WL-520GU with the latest Tomato firmware). As far as DNS, no, I'm just using my default DNS settings provided by my ISP (Shaw).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading many posts by others having the same issue and almost going bald from all my hair pulling, the cause seems to be fairly simple (and stupid). I believe that the problem developed from a certificate issue. I had originally used the Windows Live Custom Domains service to get a *.homeserver.com domain for my home server. Somehow, adding that to my fresh install created the issue.

So what I did was set up a temporary domain with the HP Personal Domian Name by TZO.com service and now everything is working just fine. I later was able to go back and change the temporary domain back to the WLCD service.